# Javascript: Put time picker into input field

Tags: javascript

I am tring to integrate a time picker into my webpage. I'm using [Bulma Calender](https://bulma-calendar.onrender.com/#features) for this.

However, results are only displayed and stored in the input field, when the "Validate" button in the time picker is pressed. For my purpose, I also want to put the selected information into the input field, when the "Validate" button is not pressed (e.g. just click anywhere else on the webpage after choosing a time).

In bulma calendar there is a hide event, which I am able to trigger and to put the results into console:
`console.log(datepicker.data.value());`

However, I am not able to put the selected time into the input field.

I already tried stuff like:

```
document.querySelector('#my-element').value=datepicker.data.value();
document.getElementById('my-element').value=datepicker.data.value();
```

but none of them is working.

Any idea what I need to change?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="http://xn--spth-moa.eu/bulma-calendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="http://xn--spth-moa.eu/bulma-calendar.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="height:100px; width:200px;">
    <input class="input" type="time" id="my-element">
    <script>
      // Initialize all input of date type.
      const calendars = bulmaCalendar.attach('[type="time"]', {
        type: "time",
        displayMode: "default"
      });


      // To access to bulmaCalendar instance of an element
      const element = document.querySelector('#my-element');
      if (element) {
        // bulmaCalendar instance is available as element.bulmaCalendar
        element.bulmaCalendar.on('hide', datepicker => {
          //what do i need to enter here?
          console.log(datepicker.data.value());
        });
      }
    </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, there is a `save` method used to set calendar data into the UI.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="http://xn--spth-moa.eu/bulma-calendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="http://xn--spth-moa.eu/bulma-calendar.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="height:100px; width:200px;">
    <input class="input" type="time" id="my-element">
    <script>
      // Initialize all input of date type.
      const calendars = bulmaCalendar.attach('[type="time"]', {
        type: "time",
        displayMode: "default"
      });


      // To access to bulmaCalendar instance of an element
      const element = document.querySelector('#my-element');
      if (element) {
        // bulmaCalendar instance is available as element.bulmaCalendar
        element.bulmaCalendar.on('hide', datepicker => {
          //what do i need to enter here?
          datepicker.data.save();
        });
      }
    </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How do I know, that it needs to be datepicker.data.save(), not datepicker.save() or something like that?